# Docker Build Kitura Sqift Container - Shim.h mysql.h file not found

Tags: docker, kitura

i am trying to move my current Kitura Dev setup into a real running environment by first moving it into a Docker Container to later migrate it to a Cloud Provider.

However while trying to build my Docker Setup for Kitura i run into problems i did not find any proper solution how to fix these.

I am Building my docker Container from The instructions from this page 
https://www.kitura.io/docs/deploying/docker.html

But i am also using SwiftKuery with MySQL in the package.

My Docker Tools file looks like the following

```
FROM ibmcom/swift-ubuntu:5.0.2
##FROM swift:5.0.2

LABEL maintainer="IBM Swift Engineering at IBM Cloud"
LABEL Description="Template Dockerfile that extends the ibmcom/swift-ubuntu image."

# We can replace this port with what the user wants
EXPOSE 8080 1024 1025

# Default user if not provided
ARG bx_dev_user=root
ARG bx_dev_userid=1000

# Install system level packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
##RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo libcurl4-openssl-dev openssl libssl-dev pkg-config libmysqlclient-dev

# Add utils files
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM-Swift/swift-ubuntu-docker/master/utils/tools-utils.sh /swift-utils/tools-utils.sh
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM-Swift/swift-ubuntu-docker/master/utils/common-utils.sh /swift-utils/common-utils.sh
RUN chmod -R 555 /swift-utils

# Create user if not root
RUN if [ "$bx_dev_user" != root ]; then useradd -ms /bin/bash -u $bx_dev_userid $bx_dev_user; fi

# Make password not required for sudo.
# This is necessary to run 'tools-utils.sh debug' script when executed from an interactive shell.
# This will not affect the deploy container.
RUN echo "$bx_dev_user ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/user && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/user

#Install some further SSL related flaws
##RUN  find / -name libssl.so.1.1 -type f -print

# Bundle application source & binaries
COPY . /swift-project
```

I get the following error

```
[5/24] Compiling Swift Module 'SwiftKueryMySQL' (3 sources)
[6/24] Compiling Swift Module 'KituraContracts' (9 sources)
<module-includes>:1:10: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#include "shim.h"
         ^
/swift-project/.build-ubuntu/checkouts/SwiftKueryMySQL/Sources/CMySQL/shim.h:3:10: error: 'mysql.h' file not found
#include <mysql.h>
         ^
/swift-project/.build-ubuntu/checkouts/SwiftKueryMySQL/Sources/SwiftKueryMySQL/MySQLConnection.swift:21:8: error: could not build C module 'CMySQL'
import CMySQL
       ^
```

after using this commands

```
docker build -t myapp-build -f Dockerfile-tools .
```

The First one still works

```
docker run -v $PWD:/swift-project -w /swift-project myapp-build /swift-utils/tools-utils.sh build release
```

Error Appears while Building the Container

Any one has an idea what i could do to fix this issue ... ?

UPDATE:

I tried one provided suggestion to add a .swift-build-linux file 
with one entry

```
swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/mysql/
```

Into the source files of my project .

up on running the command:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/swift-project -w /swift-project myapp-build /swift-utils/tools-utils.sh build release
```

It seems to pick it up as you can see below... but still i run into the same issue :(

```
Current folder: /swift-project
Command: build
Build configuration: release
Build folder: /swift-project/.build-ubuntu
Compiling the project...
Build configuration: release
Custom build command: swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/mysql/££
warning: you may be able to install mysqlclient using your system-packager:
     apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

[1/27] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/Logger.cpp
[2/27] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/MemoryManager.cpp
[3/27] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/Properties.cpp
[4/27] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/LogManager.cpp
[5/26] Compiling Swift Module 'SwiftKueryMySQL' (3 sources)
[6/26] Compiling Swift Module 'KituraContracts' (9 sources)
[7/26] Compiling Swift Module 'CloudFoundryEnv' (6 sources)
[8/26] Compiling CHTTPParser utils.c
[9/26] Linking ./.build-ubuntu/x86_64-unknown-linux/release/libagentcore.so
[10/26] Compiling CHTTPParser http_parser.c
<module-includes>:1:10: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#include "shim.h"
         ^
/swift-project/.build-ubuntu/checkouts/SwiftKueryMySQL/Sources/CMySQL/shim.h:3:10: error: 'mysql.h' file not found
#include <mysql.h>
         ^
/swift-project/.build-ubuntu/checkouts/SwiftKueryMySQL/Sources/SwiftKueryMySQL/MySQLConnection.swift:21:8: error: could not build C module 'CMySQL'
import CMySQL
       ^
Kais-MacBook-Pro:beautylivery_server_mqsql kaibaier$ docker run -v $PWD:/swift-project -w /swift-project myapp-build /swift-utils/tools-utils.sh build release
Current folder: /swift-project
Command: build
Build configuration: release
Build folder: /swift-project/.build-ubuntu
Compiling the project...
Build configuration: release
Custom build command: swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/mysql/
warning: you may be able to install mysqlclient using your system-packager:
     apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

[1/33] Compiling CHTTPParser http_parser.c
[2/39] Compiling CHTTPParser utils.c
[3/65] Compiling Swift Module 'TypeDecoder' (2 sources)
[4/65] Compiling Swift Module 'Socket' (3 sources)
[5/65] Compiling Swift Module 'Signals' (1 sources)
[6/65] Compiling Swift Module 'Logging' (3 sources)
[7/65] Compiling Swift Module 'KituraTemplateEngine' (1 sources)
[8/65] Compiling Swift Module 'Cryptor' (11 sources)
[9/65] Compiling memplugin MemoryPlugin.cpp
[10/65] Compiling Swift Module 'LoggerAPI' (1 sources)
[11/65] Compiling hcapiplugin APIConnector.cpp
[12/65] Linking ./.build-ubuntu/x86_64-unknown-linux/release/libmemplugin.so
[13/65] Compiling envplugin envplugin.cpp
[14/65] Linking ./.build-ubuntu/x86_64-unknown-linux/release/libhcapiplugin.so
[15/65] Compiling cpuplugin cpuplugin.cpp
[16/65] Compiling Swift Module 'SwiftKuery' (49 sources)
[17/65] Compiling Swift Module 'KituraContracts' (9 sources)
[18/65] Compiling Swift Module 'HeliumLogger' (2 sources)
[19/65] Compiling Swift Module 'SSLService' (2 sources)
[20/65] Compiling Swift Module 'Health' (3 sources)
[21/65] Compiling Swift Module 'FileKit' (1 sources)
[22/65] Compiling Swift Module 'Configuration' (5 sources)
[23/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/connector/configuration/ConfigurationConnector.cpp
[24/65] Linking ./.build-ubuntu/x86_64-unknown-linux/release/libenvplugin.so
[25/65] Linking ./.build-ubuntu/x86_64-unknown-linux/release/libcpuplugin.so
[26/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/connector/ConnectorManager.cpp
[27/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/agent/threads/WorkerThread.cpp
[28/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/agent/threads/ThreadPool.cpp
[29/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/agent/SystemReceiver.cpp
[30/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/agent/BucketList.cpp
[31/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/agent/Bucket.cpp
[32/65] Compiling Swift Module 'CloudFoundryEnv' (6 sources)
[33/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/agent/Agent.cpp
[34/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/monitoring/Plugin.cpp
[35/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/util/sysUtils.cpp
[36/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/util/strUtils.cpp
[37/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/util/LibraryUtils.cpp
[38/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/util/FileUtils.cpp
[39/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/port/linux/Thread.cpp
[40/65] Compiling Swift Module 'SwiftKueryMySQL' (3 sources)
[41/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/port/linux/Process.cpp
[42/65] Compiling agentcore ibmras/common/port/ThreadData.cpp
<module-includes>:1:10: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#include "shim.h"
         ^
/swift-project/.build-ubuntu/checkouts/SwiftKueryMySQL/Sources/CMySQL/shim.h:3:10: error: 'mysql.h' file not found
#include <mysql.h>
         ^
/swift-project/.build-ubuntu/checkouts/SwiftKueryMySQL/Sources/SwiftKueryMySQL/MySQLConnection.swift:21:8: error: could not build C module 'CMySQL'
import CMySQL
       ^
```

UPDATE :

It seems to work after i added this line in my Dockerfile-tools . :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo libmysqlclient-dev
```

... but now i get a new error i first have to investigate ...

```
[19/20] Compiling Swift Module 'Beautylivery_Server_New' (1 sources) [20/20] Linking ./.build-ubuntu/x86_64-unknown-linux/release/Beautylivery_Server_New clang-7: error: unable to execute command: Bus error clang-7: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation) <unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 254 (use -v to see invocation)
```

UPDATE - Resolution:

Ok i added the entry

```
swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/mysql/
```

to the new created .swift-build-linux file in the root directory in my project. (previously i had a small spelling mistake in the line).

Now i was able to pass this step of the Dockerisation process ... :)

UPDATE - NEW Problem:

Hello Together, i was running in a new problem related to the tutorial and this is to run the conatainer after building it: As i assume it is a different topic, i have raised a new question:
[Run Kitura Docker Image causes libmysqlclient.so.18 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536481/run-kitura-docker-image-causes-libmysqlclient-so-18-error)

its is that up on running the container, i get an error message:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thanks a lot for the Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `ibmcom/swift-ubuntu:5.0.2` image is built on top of Ubuntu 14.04. The version of `libmysqlclient-dev` supplied with 14.04 does not include the pkg-config information that allows the Swift compiler to find the headers without help.

There are two solutions to this problem:

1: You could add `-Xcc -I/usr/include/mysql/` arguments to the `swift build` command. Either:

- replace the command you are executing in the build container with `swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/mysql/`, or
- if you'd like to keep using the `tools-utils.sh` script, you can create a file in your project called `.swift-build-linux` which contains a single line: `swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/mysql/`  - this will be picked up by the `tools-utils.sh` script when it runs the build.

2: You can replace your base images with `FROM swift:5.0.2` (for the build image) and `FROM swift:5.0.2-slim` (for the run image) - these are the official Swift-maintained images which are based on Ubuntu 18.04, and as of the Swift 5.0.2 release, provide a 'slim' image similar to ibmcom's 'runtime' image.

- Note that these images do not bundle the `libssl-dev` or `libcurl4-openssl-dev` dependencies, so you will need to include those in your `Dockerfile-tools`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the heplful answer... the approach number two i already tried an dramatically failed with the ssl topics you described. actually needed me to re think the possibility of using the initial package from ibm.

Comment: I now tried your first suggestion with bullet point 2. i tried to directly locate the .swift-build-linux file within the root structure of my project. Same level as the sources directory. BUT this does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: I moved the file into the Sources directory an it seems to pick it up... but it still throws the sameerror

Comment: It seems to work after i added this line in my Dockerfile-tools . : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo libmysqlclient-dev ... but now i get a new error i first have to investigate ... [19/20] Compiling Swift Module 'Beautylivery_Server_New' (1 sources)
[20/20] Linking ./.build-ubuntu/x86_64-unknown-linux/release/Beautylivery_Server_New
clang-7: error: unable to execute command: Bus error
clang-7: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
<unknown>:0: error: link command failed with exit code 254 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Ok, got it... i have to move the file again out of the sources dir. previously i had some small mistakes in the entry of the file... now it seems to work .... 100 ! Thanks David Jones :)

Comment: @Bliv_Dev Any update on this issue? I ran into this also. Is there any "silver bullet" by now? It's a bit hard to know which of these suggestions to follow... I'll try them one by one, for now... also: do I have to install mysql in the docker somehow?

Comment: Hey Jonny, swift build -Xcc -I/usr/include/mysql/ did the trick for me as you can find it in the update. if you describe your problem a little bit more i might can help.