# Run Kitura Docker Image causes libmysqlclient.so.18 Error

Tags: swift, docker, kitura

after i had some previous problem to Dockerise my MySQL Kitura SETUP here : [Docker Build Kitura Sqift Container - Shim.h mysql.h file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486811/docker-build-kitura-sqift-container-shim-h-mysql-h-file-not-found/57491487#57491487)

I am running in a new Problem i can not solve following the Guide from : https://www.kitura.io/docs/deploying/docker.html .

After i followed all the steps and also did the fixing on the MySQL issue previously i was now able to run the following command :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -it myapp-run
```

THis however leads to the following issue :

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i assume something tries again to open the libmysqclclient from some wrong Environmental Directories ?

But how can i fix this issues by building the docker images ... is there any way and better a smart way ?

Thanks a lot again for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to update and enhance my dockerfile this is now running smoothly and also can be used for CI and CD tasks.

```
    FROM ibmcom/swift-ubuntu-runtime:latest
    ##FROM ibmcom/swift-ubuntu-runtime:5.0.1

    LABEL maintainer="IBM Swift Engineering at IBM Cloud"
    LABEL Description="Template Dockerfile that extends the ibmcom/swift-ubuntu-runtime image."

    # We can replace this port with what the user wants
    EXPOSE 8080

    # Default user if not provided
    ARG bx_dev_user=root
    ARG bx_dev_userid=1000

    # Install system level packages
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo libmysqlclient-dev

    # Add utils files
    ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM-Swift/swift-ubuntu-docker/master/utils/run-utils.sh /swift-utils/run-utils.sh
    ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM-Swift/swift-ubuntu-docker/master/utils/common-utils.sh /swift-utils/common-utils.sh
    RUN chmod -R 555 /swift-utils

    # Create user if not root
    RUN if [ $bx_dev_user != "root" ]; then useradd -ms /bin/bash -u $bx_dev_userid $bx_dev_user; fi

    # Bundle application source & binaries
    COPY ./.build /swift-project/.build

    # Command to start Swift application
    CMD [ "sh", "-c", "cd /swift-project && .build/release/Beautylivery_Server_New" ]
```

Comment: Awesome, adding `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo libmysqlclient-dev` to Dockerfile did it for me. I mistakenly added it to Dockerfile-tools first. I had the exact same problems as you, getting mysql to run using Kitura in Docker. 